# TemporalTipe.Time parameter in jpql

Tags: jpa, time, eclipselink, jpql

I want filter by **Time** in **jpql** but I think that I´m not doing well.
`SELECT e FROM Pedido e WHERE e.fechaEntrega = :fechaInicio AND e.horaEntrega < :horaEntrega` and `que.setParameter("horaEntrega", horaEntrega, TemporalType.TIME);` but when i see return this not filter by *horaEntrega*. I'm using **eclipselink 2.5** any idea???
I tryed use `SELECT e FROM Pedido e WHERE e.fechaEntrega = :fechaInicio AND  CAST(e.horaEntrega AS TIMESTAMP) < :horaEntrega` and doesn´t work and if i try cast to **Time** says me that expected **NUMBER** and got **DATE**
It´s weird when I write **SELECT** in sql im using `cast(cast(etretst as timestamp) as time) < '08:00:00'` and this works fine. And when I write this say me that expected **TIME** not a **DATE**

Comment: I´m thinking use **TO_CHAR(horaEntrega, 'HH24:MI')** but I don´t like this solution

Comment: Not enough information. How is the entity defined. What are the rows in the table, what do you pass as parameter to the query, and what does it return?

Comment: horaEntrega is **Date** in database and param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved **SELECT** `SELECT e FROM Pedido e WHERE e.fechaPedido = :fechaInicio AND CAST(CAST(e.horaPedido AS TIMESTAMP) AS TIME) < :horaZona` and parameter is `que.setParameter("horaZona", new Time(horaPedido.getTime()).toString());`